# How do you print out a linked list of the following implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I just finished the program that makes a linked list and should also print out the contents.  Its compiles properly and appears to make the linked list, but doesn't seem to print out anything.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



struct DeltaTimerNode
{
    int timerInterval;
    DeltaTimerNode *next;
    DeltaTimerNode(int tempTimeInt, DeltaTimerNode *tempNext = NULL)
    {
        timerInterval = tempTimeInt;
        next = tempNext;
    }
};


DeltaTimerNode *deltaTimerList = NULL;
void insert(int deltaTimerValue)
{
    deltaTimerList = new DeltaTimerNode (deltaTimerValue, deltaTimerList);

}




int main()
{
    int tickTime;
    char choice;

    vector<int> rawTimers;
//int i = 0; Originally used for tracking something.  Moved logic to different function.


    do 
    {

        cout<< "Input timer value (not delta timer)." << endl;
        cin >> tickTime; //Input regular value of timer, not the delta time.  That will be converted automatically.
        rawTimers.push_back(tickTime);
        //i++;
        cout<< "Are there more timer values?  Input y for yes, n for no."<<endl;
        cin >> choice;

    }
    while(choice == 'y');


    sort (rawTimers.begin(), rawTimers.end());

    DeltaTimerNode *deltaTimerList = NULL;

    for (int j = 0; j < rawTimers.size(); j++) //for loop populates list.
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            insert (rawTimers[0]);
        }

        else
        {
            insert (rawTimers[j] - rawTimers[j-1]);
        }

    }


    DeltaTimerNode *ptr = deltaTimerList;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        cout << ptr -> timerInterval << " "; //should print out stuff here.
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile because a semicolon is missing after `cout<< "Are there more timer values?  Input y for yes, n for no."<<endl`

Comment: when do you update DeltaTimerNode *deltaTimerList? I see you init it as NULL and do not update anywhere else?

Comment: @shole, it's done in the call to `insert` (albeit in a somewhat unconventional way). However, MikeCAT has discovered the issue, the list being scanned in the output loop is shadowing the global list, and it is set to NULL and never changed.

Comment: oh yea I smell it is related to that pointer but did not see that he declared twice...good job @MikeCAT

Answer (score 2):

You declared a local variable `deltaTimerList` and shadowed the gloval variable `deltaTimerList`. Remove the harmful declaration

```
DeltaTimerNode *deltaTimerList = NULL;
```

from `main()`.

Also note that you should destroy via `delete` whatever you created via `new`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the default constructor within struct and no need for insert() function and the global variable. Just create a new node and assign your pointer to be the new node, every time you use a node. I hope you get the idea and this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct DeltaTimerNode
{
    int timerInterval;
    DeltaTimerNode *next;
};

int main()
{
int tickTime;
char choice;
vector<int> rawTimers;

do
{
    cout << "Input timer value (not delta timer)." << endl;
    cin >> tickTime; //Input regular value of timer, not the delta time.  That will be converted automatically.
    rawTimers.push_back(tickTime);

    cout << "Are there more timer values?  Input y for yes, n for no." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
} while (choice == 'y');

sort(rawTimers.begin(), rawTimers.end());

DeltaTimerNode deltaTimerList;
DeltaTimerNode* head = &deltaTimerList;

for (int j = 0; j < rawTimers.size(); j++) //for loop populates list.
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        head->timerInterval = rawTimers[j];
        head->next = new DeltaTimerNode();
        head = head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        head->timerInterval = rawTimers[j] - rawTimers[j - 1];
        head->next = new DeltaTimerNode();
        head = head->next;
    }
}

head = &deltaTimerList;
while (head->next != NULL)
{
    cout << head->timerInterval << " "; //should print out stuff here.
    head = head->next;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thing is though I have to use the insert method I had.  Or something like it.  Basically there has to be a specific method for inserting a node in the list.

Comment: I bit there is no direct insert method for linked lists. and the only way is to create a new node on every move. But take a look at this and I appreciate any upvote or/and mark as an answer

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/